# Trouble understanding render targets and back buffers in monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

My graphics device is set up as follows:

```
GraphicsDeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager(GameBase.GameRef);
GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 640;
GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
GraphicsDeviceManager.ApplyChanges();
```

I can't find anywhere on google explaining exactly what the preferred back buffer width means.

I set up a render target like this:

```
RenderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(
    GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice,
    640,
    480,
    false,
    GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat,
    DepthFormat.Depth24);
```

I can't find anything on google about what the 640 and 480 actually mean with respect to how the render target is drawn.

The problem I have is that if I resize the window, everything stretches. I'm trying to understand what monogame is doing to cause this, and then finally figure out a solution.

At the start my window is 640x480 and the PreferredBackBufferWidth and height are 640/480 and the render target is 640/480

If I resize the window to 1920x1080 for example, everything stretches, so somehow monogame no longer rendering the 640x480 texture onto a 640x480 part of the screen, but I haven't changed any of the values or done any code for this.

If I resize the screen, should the render target be destroyed and recreated at the new size of the window, or should the back buffer width and height be changed, or both, or something else?

I am very confused and there isn't any documentation online technical enough to answer in detail. Once I understand it I should be able to write some code so that when you resize the screen nothing happens, everything stay the same size, and there is a black area around the right/bottom edge because the window is larger than what i'm rendering to.

Comment: Can't check it right now. But as far as I remember, both should be resized. Think of back buffer as of the "paper that you are drawing at" while the RenderTarget is "the plane you're projecting your already drawn picture to". So if you don't want stretching, then you need to change back buffer to have more space on the "paper" and then change RenderTarget to actually have some "place to show your drawing".

Comment: So i a simple (example) scenario, your back buffer should have the maximum size you are planning to target.

Comment: I know what you mean, back in the day when XNA was alive it was easy to find help on XNA tutorials rather than skeleton reference topics on MSDN.  The best I can find is [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195022.aspx), there's a bit there on aspect ratio's too.  Hope it helps

Comment: What are you using the `RenderTarget` for? If you're just doing simple drawing to the screen, a separate render target is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The back buffer is a special render target that is displayed on the screen. It  is stretched to fill the window, which results in scaling if the window size does not match.

You can resize the back buffer when the window size changes. The `Game.Window.ClientSizeChanged` event is fired when that happens (note that it may be fired multiple times if the user is resizing the window by dragging). Then resizing the back buffer is simply

```
GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Window.ClientBounds.Width;
GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Window.ClientBounds.Height;
GraphicsDeviceManager.ApplyChanges();
```

Whether you should recreate the `RenderTarget` depends on what you're using it for.

Comment: I would like the ability to stretch the output to fit the window size, but turn this on/off as an option. Sometimes I want it to stretch, and sometimes I want to render more of the screen (so you see more 'tiles' in the game). Presumably both should be the same size then. I will experiment with this.